# (De)referencing method variant in Java Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

Consider the code:

**Example 1**

```
var Executors = java.util.concurrent.Executors;
var executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
var fork = function (callable) {
    // Clarify Runnable versus Callable overloaded methods
    executor['submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)'](callable);
};

fork(function(){ ... }); //ok
```

This works.

But this does not work:

**Example 2**

```
var Executors = java.util.concurrent.Executors;
var executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
var fork = executor['submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)'];

fork(function(){ ... }); //fails, NullPointerException
```

I assume, it is because `fork` here is not a JS Function instance, it is actually an instance of `jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod`

I tried to use `fork.apply(executor,function() { ... });` but natrually, SimpleDynamicMethod has no `apply`.

Why is it, actually, that Example 2 does not work, while Example 1 does?

Is it simply a perk of Nashorn? It there a better way to define fork() function than in Example 1?

**Update**

In example 2,

`print(typeof fork);` reports `function`

`print(fork)` reports `[jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod Future java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Callable)]`

and exception is (with line 13 reading `fork(function() {`)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_._L5(<eval>:13)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.runScript(<eval>:5)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:527)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/nashorn_multi_threading_and_mt

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is good to have it attached to this question. I actually used it initially as a blue-print for my code, just wanted to make a nice JS module wrapping ThreadExecutor code for a server-side library. I can live with the code as in Example 1, I just feel that the extra closure is not necessary and do not understand the 'magic' behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the receiver 'executor' from the call.  In general, 'fetching' Java functions is only practical with static Java functions. For example:

```
jjs> var abs = java.lang.Math.abs;
jjs> abs(-10);
10
```

In your example, we could have bound fork to executor and make it equivalently static.  This support is currently not present.  We should probably have support for adding the receiver as the first argument if 'fetched' from a class.  Will file an enhancement request for a future release.

Comment: Ah, now it is all clear. I was getting close in my thoughts, but could not figure out the details. To call a dynamic method you do need an instance of the object and unless you have it in the context (like in example 1 it is part of the closure), Nashorn has no way of knowing what to invoke it from. I believe by adding the facility to bind functions as you described will make JavaScript coding easier. I trust there will be a review of implications, so far I like a lot how thoughtful the interoperability is. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, currently you can't use `bind`, `apply`, and `call` with POJO methods. I'd like to add that as a future enhancement. The best you can currently do in your above example is:

```
executor['submit(Callable)'](function() { ... })
```

Note that while in general indexed access to a property (using the `[]` operator) is less efficient than property name access (using the `.` operator), Nashorn recognizes indexed access with a string literal and treats it just as efficiently as a property name access, so you don't suffer a slowdown here, just a bit of visual noise. In the case above, it will actually end up getting linked to the executor's virtual method directly.

Speaking of visual noise, you don't have to fully qualify `java.util.concurrent.Callable`. When the non-qualified name of the parameter type is sufficient to disambiguate the overloads (which is pretty much always), you can just use the non-qualified name, regardless of what package it is in (works for your own classes too).

Comment: Attila, do you know if it is still the case that with JDK 8u102 you cannot call `apply()` or `call()` on methods from a Java class ? Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

In example 1, `var fork` is a function that returns array `executor`. In example 2, `var fork` is an array. That is why you cant use `()` and `apply`.

Does `fork[0](function(){...})` work for you ?

Thanks

Comment: If I replace the call with `fork[0](function() {...})` it throws
`javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod Future java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Callable)] has no such function "0" in <eval> at line number 16
 at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:563)`